# Issue with <input type="file">

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, css, file-upload

I am trying to make a form consisting of one input field of text type and other is of file type. The problem is that the **Browse** button for file is shown inside an input box. I don't want the button to be inside input box. I am attaching the screenshot. Please help me out.

Here is the code snippet.

```
<form class="form-inline fonts-calibri" action="" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="oid">Purchase Order No. </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oid" placeholder="Enter PO number" name="oid">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group pull-right" style="margin-right : 15%;">
        <label for="file">Upload PO </label>
        <input type = "file" class="form-control" id="file" name = "file" size = "50"/>
        <span><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="upload-button"><span class="fa fa-upload"></span></button></span>
     </div>             
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The box is generated by the form-control class, simply use the following code to remove the box

```
<input type = "file" id="file" name = "file" size = "50"/>
```

you can still add some other class if you need to add some styling.

Update :
If you need the form-control class,then you can add some class to it

> class="form-control test"

like so and the remove the box effects of form-control in it,

```
.form-control.test {
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: the problem is fixed after removing  form-control class, but label, browse and upload buttons are not coming in one row. They are aligned as one below the other. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `.form-control` class from the `<input type="file" />`, because this class is making the box that you don't want...!

Look the snippet below!

```css
.form-group.pull-right input {float: left;}
span {float: left;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline fonts-calibri" action="" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="oid">Purchase Order No. </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oid" placeholder="Enter PO number" name="oid">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group pull-right" style="margin-right : 15%;">
        <label for="file">Upload PO </label><div class="clearfix"></div>
        <input type = "file" id="file" name = "file" size = "50"/>
        <span><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="upload-button"><span class="fa fa-upload"></span></button></span>
     </div>             
</form>
```

Comment: thanks. 
 
the problem is fixed after removing form-control class, but label, browse and upload buttons are not coming in one row. They are aligned as one below the other. Please help

Comment: Add `float: left;` to all the element that you want make inline..!